# ProcessBuilder on Linux : error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java, command, processbuilder

I'm trying to run a command on machines that can be windows or mac.
on windows it works.
on linux it returns me the following error:

> Cannot run program "sonar-scanner" (in directory "/ var /
> cloudbees-change / workspace / cmga0 / Application /
> nfbe0_core-factoring-practices-v1 / sonar-execution / sonarScanner /
> bin"): error = 2 , No such file or directory

the sonar-scanner file exists in that path, but the process builder cannot run it.

the code i am using is the following:

```
String jarPath = utility.findJarLocation();
String sonarScannerCommand = "";
ProcessBuilder pb = null;
ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
if (parameters.getSistemaOperativo().equals("w")) { // if windows
    pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c");
    pb.directory(new File(jarPath + "/sonarScanner/bin"));
    lista.add("sonar-scanner.bat");
} else if (parameters.getSistemaOperativo().equals("l")) {// if linux
    pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c");
    pb.directory(new File(jarPath + "/sonarScanner/bin"));
    lista.add("sonar-scanner");
} else if (parameters.getSistemaOperativo().equals("m")) {// if mac
    pb = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c");
    pb.directory(new File(jarPath + "/sonarScanner/bin"));
    lista.add("sonar-scanner");
}

sonarScannerCommand = parameters.getSonarScannerParameters();
String[] split = sonarScannerCommand.trim().split(" ");

for (String string : split) {
    lista.add(string);
}

pb.command(lista);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process pr = pb.start();
    
public String findJarLocation() throws URISyntaxException {
    String jarPath = Utility.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath();
    String jarName = jarPath.substring(jarPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    String[] split = jarPath.split(jarName);
    return split[0];
}
```

is it a path problem? do i need to add some information to the proccess builder in case the machine is linux?

A thousand thanks

Comment: ` error = 2 , No such file or directory` means the executable `sonar-scanner` is not in path. if you want to execute a which is in the current folder you should use `./sonar-scanner` and make sure that the user has execute permission on the file.

Comment: Wrong directory capitalization on Linux? Did you try `ls` on that path string?

Comment: Also you might be overwriting the constructor args of `sh -c` with `pb.command(lista);`? https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.java#L238

Comment: Maybe the sonarscanner file does not have the exxecutable bit set? This could be a problem after an installer simply unzipped the files on Unix.

Comment: @akarnokd adding `sh` to the lista solved the problem. a thousand thanks